# have jenkins start an EC2 instance and Terminating it

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins

I have a full deployment job that takes an ip of a running instance and deploys my system on it.

I currently hold an EC2 instance for automation tests that run every night, but the instance is expensive and im looking for a way to initiate it before the tests and terminate it after the test.

I looked for EC2 plugins that can help and the closest one was [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin) but this is for making slaves and thats not what I want.

I want to be able to launch an EC2 instance, and pass its IP address to the automation tests job, then terminate that instance once done.

I started making a command line bash file for this, but this seems like too much work, and I thought maybe there is something im missing.

Comment: why dont you make jenkins run a  shell script and inside that shell script write the command to run EC2 and then another to kill after work is done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your requirement is valid and amazon knows:

When you stop an instance, we shut it down. We don't charge usage for a stopped instance, or data transfer fees, but we do charge for the storage for any Amazon EBS volumes.

Reference :
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html

Here some approaches to start/stop your instaces

## Amazon EC2 HTTP API

This is an api rest and you can perform a **simple http request** to start or stop your instance:

- [Amazon EC2 API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)
- [Start Instance endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_StartInstances.html)

```
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=StartInstances&...
```

- [Stop Instance endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_StopInstances.html)

```
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=StopInstances&...
```

You can invoke this api **from Jenkins** in many ways : simple shell execution,groovy and scripted/declarative, pipelines.

---

## AWS CLI

- [start instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/start-instances.html)
- [stop instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/stop-instances.html)

Here more about how suspend instances using aws cli:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-suspend-resume-processes.html
- Also with powershell: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html

You can invoke this api **from Jenkins** in many ways : simple shell execution,groovy and scripted/declarative, pipelines.

---

## AWS Instance Scheduler

In 2018, AWS launched the AWS Instance Scheduler, a new and improved scheduling solution that enables customers to schedule Amazon EC2 instances.

With this tool you can automatically start and stop the Amazon EC2 and Amazon RDS instances.

Reference :

- https://aws.amazon.com/answers/infrastructure-management/instance-scheduler/

With this approach you **don't need Jenkins** :b

Comment: Well I feel stupid now. will do just that. Thanks for the detailed answer. But how can I know that the instance is actually up before starting to run the automation suite?

Comment: nevermind.. Found this: aws ec2 wait instance-running --instance-ids "i-XXXXXXXX"

Comment: No worries. Almost all user interface actions in aws web platform, you can do them with http api rest or aws cli. Also it would be interesting, develop a jenkins plugin to reduce even more this steps.